# Putting elliptic curves into the Weierstrass form

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

How would one put the elliptic curve
$$Y^2 = a_3 X^3 + a_2 X^2 + a_1 X + a_0$$
into the Weierstrass form:
$$y^2 = 4x^3 - g_2x - g_3,$$
that is, what change of variables will one need to use?

**Update**: It looks like
$$X = x - \frac{a_2}{3a_3}, \quad Y = \frac{y}{2}$$
works.

Comment: $X=x-a_3/12$, $Y=y$.

Answer (score 1):

First put $X=(a_3/4)X_1$ and $Y=(a_3^2/16) Y_1$. You get an equation of the form
$$Y_1^2=4X_1^3+b_1X_1^2+b_2X_1+b_3$$
Now let $Y_1=y$ and $X_1=x-b_1/12$ (as per Felix Klein's suggestion).